# Sorting on Eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent, fluent

I have a simple table on a page that outputs a paginated list of baseball games. It shows the game date, the local and visiting teams, and the city. I have three Eloquent models (Game, Team and City), all relationships are working and all is good. I love being able to do `$game->localTeam->city->fullName` (a mutator that combines the city and state).

The data comes from the following query: `Game::with('teamHome', 'teamVisitor', 'teamHome.city')`. I want to be able to sort by any column. But if I use `->orderBy()` on the query, it only allows to sort the results from the games table. I can't find a way to sort on the team or the city. From what I read, I would need to do a Fluent query and join all my tables. But then, I would have an array of stdClass objects and wouldn't be able to navigate in my Eloquent relationships and use the fullName mutator described above.

This scenario seems so basic, there must be an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you do it like $game->localTeam->sortBy('name') and $game->localTeam->city->sortyBy('name') ? (assuming Team and City has name properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sortBy` method after doing `->get()`. This will get the collection and then sort it.

Otherwise you can do a RAW query but you lose the fluent syntax.

Comment: Yes, but that would only sort the results from that paginated page, right?

Comment: You are right! Maybe you have to do with a Query Builder, like you said. From Laravel 5.3 it returns a collection